# Are any of the hieroglyphs, runes, etc. appearing in Stargate intelligible/meaningful?

Tags: stargate

The Stargate franchise is built around the notion of extraterrestrial visitors in Earth's ancient past, connecting many ancient Earth cultures with fictional extraterrestrial races such as the Goa'uld, Asgard, etc.. As a result, we often see a lot of Egyptian hieroglyphics, Norse runes, and other writing forms on screen. Where there is ***supposed to be*** a correlation with ancient Earth languages (regardless of origin), do the symbols actually make sense? Are they just random/arbitrarily chosen symbols? Do they form intelligible phrases? Do they contain production in-jokes? If so, what do they say?

Examples of alien writing:

- **Stargate symbols.** Representations of constellations; non-linguistic and therefore **out of the scope** of my question.
- **Hieroglyphics.** Look like Ancient Egyptian. Stargate mythology associates such writing with the language of the Goa'uld. Do any of the symbols appearing on obviously Goa'uld artifacts (resurrection sarcophagus, walls of Goa'uld ships, etc.) form readable phrases according to modern understanding of Ancient Egyptian?
- **Runes.** Looks like ancient Norse writing. Stargate mythology associates such writing with the language of the Asgard. Do any of the runes where they appear in a technological or extra-terrestrial setting (as in episodes "Thor's Hammer", "Thor's Chariot", etc.) actually form readable Runic phrases?
- **Ancient.** Looks more like a bar code than any natural language. Although Daniel Jackson associates spoken Ancient (one of the "four races") with Latin, the written form is **obviously made-up** for the show.
- **Nox and Furling.** Writing appears in one or perhaps two episodes in which they are implicitly or explicitly identified as members of the "four races". Their languages are never associated with any human language, so any writings we might see must be made-up and therefore **out of the scope** of my question.
- **The Goa'uld system lord Yu** wears clothing or other artifacts, or appears in settings upon which Asian (specifically Chinese?) symbols sometimes appear. Are these symbols meaningful in the context of their appearance?

I believe there are a few other examples of alien writings which Jackson associates with languages of the ancient Middle East or South Asia - Babylonian, Cuneiform(?) etc.. Does any of this writing which appears on screen actually form readable phrases, either meaningful in context or joke-full for the production staff?

Comment: I assume you're not referring to the symbols on the stargate itself, which mostly represent constellations.

Comment: I'm assuming that he's referring to, for instance, the languages of the 4 races...http://www.gateworld.net/wiki/Alliance_of_Four_Races

Comment: The Goa'uld hieroglyphs were based on actual Egyptian hieroglyphs (but the show claimed the reverse of course). The Asgard runes contain actual Viking runes I believe.

Comment: @JohnSensebe Yes, excluding the constellation symbols, referring only to those which have or seem to have a linguistic nature - like hierogloyhics, runes, etc.

Comment: @Paulie_D I've edited my question to (hopefully) clarify its scope.

Comment: I know that there have been **attempts** at converting some of the hieroglyphs to letters...you can see that at Wikipedia but whether they are *meaningful* is open to interpretation.

Comment: Somebody translated the instrument panel of a jumper, but I'm not sure where I saw it or how accurate it was.

Comment: I think you've muddled [Norse runes](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runes), which would be a logical partner for myths of Asgard, with something Celtic (maybe you're thinking of [Ogham](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ogham)?) which would be an entirely different culture and mythology.

Comment: @IMSoP Yes, you're right, thanks! I've corrected my question accordingly. Not sure why I originally said Celtic other than I thought (perhaps mistakenly) that Vikings had a significant presence in the British Isles, and I assumed that it included influence on / injection into language and culture. Never heard of Ogham til now,.

Answer (score 2):

There is at least one case of ancient languages having meaning. As described in [this excellent answer from Bamboo](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/97343/13217), the puddle jumper console (primarily appearing in *Stargate Atlantis*, occasionally appearing in *Stargate SG-1*) has messages written in Ancient.

[image: copilot side of the console]

In-universe, Ancient is a precursor language to Latin. However, the usage on the console is an English substitution cipher. If you replace the Ancient letters with English ones (and add spaces and punctuation), you see an apparently in-universe warning message about improper use of gate travel and the ship's cloaking device.

> Gate protocols must be set before launch sequence.
>   Never attempt gate reentry when in cloak m??? [mode?]

Comment: Hey, that's my old answer!  Neat.  For what it's worth, all of the ancient writing in the Atlantis gate room (the text that lights up on the steps going up to the command center) can be similarly translated to English.  I did it once, but don't seem to have my translation any more.

Comment: @Bamboo I hope it's okay to share this info. If you wanted to take credit for this by posting your own answer, or expanding it, I'll be happy to delete mine.

Comment: Oh no, it's totally cool.  I was thinking about digging up my gateroom translation and adding it to this, or maybe creating a separate question specifically about translations to english.  I'm sure there are plenty of others besides the gateroom and the jumper... those are just the only two I've done.

Comment: @Bamboo The question asker was asking for several instances of translations. I think that either an expanded answer to this question, or a new self-answered question for just Atlantis stuff, would be great and I'd probably give you a bounty like I did for your last answer.

Comment: Cool.  I just posted a Question/Answer with the gateroom translation.  Hopefully other people will find some other instances.  I think there are a number of them.  I vaguely recall someone in production at a convention saying there were lots of little phrases scattered around atlantis on consoles and viewscreens, etc.  I figured since there are a number of them, it's worth it's own question.

Comment: My question was about writing which isn't in made-up languages/glyphs such as "Ancient" (Lantean/Alteran), but is written in actual real-world out-of-universe ancient languages or at least borrows their glyphs (like ancient Egyptian and runic). While the Ancient example is entertaining, it doesn't fall within the scope of my question.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the hieroglyphs are just a repeating series of a few glyphs. Some Hieroglyphic texts are intelligible though. [See my answer for this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/41162/i-want-to-speak-the-goauld-language-where-to-get-started/193051#193051) for a detailed explanation for the "Rosetta Stone" text in the original movie.